# Питон будто бы выполняет инструкции параллельно

Tags: python, консоль

Основная суть в том, что при использовании `sys.stdout.write()` и `sys.stdin.read()`, `sys.stdout.write()` не успевает вывести все содержимое, т.к. будто-бы срабатывает ожидания введения `ctrl + q` для выхода из бесконечного цикла ввода `sys.stdin.read()`. Хотя команды записаны последовательно, многопоточность не использовал. Возможно, это издержки реализации `tty`(`termios`) в питоне, я не знаю. Использую сырой режим(`raw mode`) с параметрами `VMIN = 0` и `VTIME = 0`
Код вывода:

```
for y in range(1, rowCount + 1):
    for x in range(1, columnCount + 1):
        #sys.stdout.write('\x1b[' + str(y) + ';' + str(x) + 'H')                                                                                                                                            
        c = 'o'
        //Проверка на то, что курсор установлен в месте предполагаемого окна(терминальное псевдо-окно, этого весь экран успешно заполняется символами 'o'. В этом коде выделяются границы, и ставятся пробелы)
        if x in range(text['coordinates']['m1']['x'] - 1, text['coordinates']['m2']['x'] + 1) and y in range(text['coordinates']['m1']['y'] - 1, text['coordinates']['m2']['y'] + 1):
            c = ' '
            if y == text['coordinates']['m1']['y'] - 1 or y == text['coordinates']['m2']['y']:
                c = '-'
            if x == text['coordinates']['m1']['x'] - 1 or x == text['coordinates']['m2']['x']:
                c = '|'
        sys.stdout.write(c)
```

Код ввода:

```
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[H\x1b[J')
c = sys.stdin.read()
while len(c) != 1 or ord(c) != ord('q') - 96 :
    c = sys.stdin.read()
```

Эти два куска кода идут последовательно, между ними никаких других инструкций нет. Но почему-то, если убрать кусок ввода, то вывод успешно выводится. А с куском кода, вывод будто-бы не успевает закончится, и начинается ожидание ввода символа.
Я  еще специально для проверки написал между этими кусками инструкцию очищения экрана `ESC[H` `ESC[J`. Когда ввода нет, экран очищается сразу, когда ввод есть, экран очищается лишь когда я введу правильный символ(когда закончится ввод)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вывод в Python буферезирован, поэтому используйте `sys.stdout.flush()` сразу после вывода для того чтобы "сбросить буфер".

Comment: оказывается все так просто... Спасибо большое. Вы ответили достаточно быстро, я сейчас пока не могу засчитать ответ верным, как разрешат так сразу!